# Run Symfony PHP controller code after clicking on an HTML button on the same web page

Tags: php, html, symfony

How do I run a Symfony PHP controller function after clicking on an HTML button without opening other web pages in the browser?

My controller PHP code:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $sql = $this->container->get('database_connection');

        $users = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        //$tcredit=$users->getcredit();

        $sqlo = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='batman'");
        while ($row = $sqlo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $firsttime = $row['ftime'];
            $secondtime = $row['stime'];

            $finaltime = $firsttime - $secondtime;
            $dataupdate = $sql->query("UPDATE user SET ftime= '$finaltime' WHERE username ='batman'");
        }

        return $this->render('onmatchBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

HTML button  `<button type="button">to run controller click her !</button>`.

Comment: You can create a new route for this action and call it via AJAX from your frontend

Comment: Many options. Put the button inside a form, set the form to POST method, and the inject the request object in the controller function and test if the method is POST. Put a parameter in the url and test it within the controller function...

Answer (score 0):

I created new route

```
reportbutton_homepage:
    path:     /testbutton
    defaults: { _controller: reportbuttonBundle:Default:index }
```

and on my twig file I added this javascript code  and the  my url to it like that and that's worked

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function submitCouponCode()
{

    var url =
        "http://localhost/x1/sym/thesym/web/app_dev.php/testbutton" ;

    // get the URL
    http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    http.open("GET", url, true);
    http.send(null);

    // prevent form from submitting
    return false;
}

</script>

<form action="" onsubmit="return submitCouponCode();">
<input type="submit" value="Apply">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the NEW Function you can make the return linke this:

```
return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'))
```

In this case you will excute the code Insider the function and you will be redirected to the same page you are already in